# firebase.analytics is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to add analytics to an already existing web app. I initialize Firebase Analytics as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web).

---

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.analytics();
```

I get this error `TypeError: firebase.analytics is not a function`

What could the problem be?

Comment: Probably package isn't imported properly?

Comment: You're going to have to edit the question to provide enough information so that anyone can reproduce the problem.  That involves explaining how you created your project and integrated the Firebase SDK.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 8):

You have to import 'firebase/analytics' for side effects:

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app')
require('firebase/analytics')

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.analytics();
```

That worked for me

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me (Gatsby-generated blog + firebase analytics)

Answer (score 7):

You may check and initialize **Firebase Analytics v9+** like this. You may also upgrade your old versions to newer SDK.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics, logEvent, isSupported } from "firebase/analytics";

// Find this config on your firebase project overview
const firebaseConfig = { ... } // your config

// Initialize Firebase
let app = null;
let analytics = null;

isSupported().then((result) => {
    if (result) {
        app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    }
})

// simple event
logEvent(analytics, 'your_event_name');

// firebase defined events like page_view etc.
logEvent(analytics, 'page_view', `your_event_parameter`)
```

*Note:* I got an error on Docker build, that's why I call the `logEvent` like this:

```
isSupported().then((result) => {
  if (result) {
    logEvent(analytics, title);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure you initialize firebase instance correctly, it won't work if you run it in server-side, then official providers a method to check whether your environment supports analytics or not, call `firebase.analytics.isSupported()`, this is a promise, so the correct way to use it is

```
var firebaseConfig... // your config

var firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.analytics.isSupported().then((isSupported) => {
    if (isSupported) {
      analytics = firebase.analytics();
    }
})
```

Comment: This code structure works perfectly, web app now runs in the incognito browser with no analytics warning. thank you!

Comment: I got an error here, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined`

Answer (score 5):

In my case, this worked. I'm using firebase version `^8.1.2`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/analytics';
import 'firebase/auth';

...

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
```

Answer (score 3):

Analytics is not supported in Node. Check the below link for support on environments.
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk

Comment: @Bery where do you see that Analytics is supported in Node.js via that link? As of today (and that page was last updated yesterday), it says that the Analytics Firebase Product is not supported for the JS SDK in the Node.js environment. https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/environments-js-sdk#other_environments

Answer (score 2):

Try to firebase.analytics.Analytics;

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app')
require('firebase/analytics')
    
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.analytics.Analytics;
```

Comment: What is that supposed to do?? `firebase.analytics.Analytics` is simply an interface, right?

Answer (score 0):

```html
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'

firebase.analytics()
```

firebase.analytics() is updated to analytics()
if you're using react native you have to import analytics

use

```html
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics'

analytics()
```

instead importing from firebase

you need to run npm install or yarn add @react-native-firebase/analytics'

and make sure you run cd ios && pod install